# Is WSO2 APIM 4.0.0 analytics not free?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to use the analytics feature of wso2.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/getting-started-guide/

I can set-up the analytics by generating on-prem keys as shown in the above guide. However, it seems like I need a choreo subscription to use it longer than 2 weeks. Is there a free way to use APIM analytics? Is MI analytics the only alternative? I'm currently not using MI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [1], Choreo Analytics is only free upto 2 weeks and you can only have 3 on-prem keys during this period. However, as mentioned, you can extend the free subscription by [contacting WSO2 sales](https://wso2.com/contact/) and submitting a request.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/getting-started-guide/#step-1-sign-in-to-choreo

Comment: Is the free subscription extension also for a limited time? If it is, is there an alternative to Choreo? I don't necessarily need all of the Choreo features.

Comment: Yes the extension is for a limited time. There's no alternative for this at the moment.

Comment: You can publish this to ELK - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/samples/publishing-analytics-events-to-external-systems/

Comment: @Pubci It seems like I have to "Place the created .jar file inside the `wso2am-4.0.0/repository/components/lib` directory.". In Kubernetes, should I copy the jar into the working pod via 'kubectl cp' or Is it possible to do this cleaner?